# Distinguish if a C++ static method is called by the class or by an object

Tags: c++, class, function, static

Is there a way to tell if a static method of a class was invoked by a call to the class method or by a call from an object?

```
class mertz
{
   static int x(void) {....}
   ....
}

int main( ... )
{
   int c = mertz::x();
   mertz     fred;  
   ind d = fred.x();
}
```

Can x tell the difference in its invocation in for c and d?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in a portable way and probably not at all in most C++ implementations.

A static method is indeed just a global function with a funny name. You can in theory inspect the call stack to find from where the call is coming from... however the machine instructions that will be generated by the compiler most probably will be identical for both

```
mertx::x();
```

and

```
fred.x();
```

because only the static type of the instance is needed to find which is the method to call and this information is available at compile time. Therefore in both cases the call code will just call the function without any need to reference the `fred` instance.

Comment: "a global function with a funny name" +1!

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to tell the difference.  The two calls are identical.

Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're trying to do this?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a vector whose nodes are all objects of type Mertz.  I wanted a static print() method that would tell me who is on the vector and thought it might be nice to have the current Mwertz (Fred) hilighted if Fred asked for print() or skip the highlighting if Mertz asked.

Answer (score -2):

you can have both a static and a non static function with the same name

```
class mertz 
{ 
   static int x(void) {....} 
   int x(void) {....}
};
```

otherwise, as already pointed out, x has no chance of telling how it was called.